# Merge video and audio while delaying audio by x seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

This works for merging audio and video

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.ogg -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a libvorbis -ac 2 -shortest out.mp4 -y -nostdin
```

I can't figure out how to delay the audio so it starts x seconds into the video. I have tried -itsoffset but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.ogg -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=1000|1000[a1];[0:a][a1]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a libvorbis -ac 2 -shortest out.mp4 -y -nostdin
```

The `adelay` adds 1000 ms of silence to both channels of the OGG.

Comment: @Gyan can we use amix instead of amerge filter?

Comment: Sure, but then add volume=2 after amix to restore volume.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround, but you could concatenate 1 second of silence with your ogg first:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate